# Cannot fix error: OpenCV(4.1.2) esize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to replicate this code from a [repository of COVIDNet in Keras](https://github.com/busyyang/COVID-19/blob/master/preprocessing.ipynb).

I fully ran the first notebook in the repo, but in the second one, I get an error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# Set parameters here 
INPUT_SIZE = (224, 224)
mapping = {'normal': 0, 'bacteria': 1, 'viral': 2, 'COVID-19': 3}
train_filepath = 'train_split.txt'
test_filepath = 'test_split.txt'

# load in the train and test files
file = open(train_filepath, 'r') 
trainfiles = file.readlines() 
file = open(test_filepath, 'r')
testfiles = file.readlines()

# Print
print('Total samples for train: ', len(trainfiles))
print('Total samples for test: ', len(testfiles))

Total samples for train:  72696
Total samples for test:  6255

# resize to input size and normalize to 0 - 1
x_train = []
x_test = []
y_train = []
y_test = []

for i in range(len(testfiles)):
    test_i = testfiles[i].split()
    imgpath = test_i[1]
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('data', 'test', imgpath))
    img = cv2.resize(img, INPUT_SIZE) # resize
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
    x_test.append(img)
    y_test.append(mapping[test_i[2]])

print('Shape of test images: ', x_test[0].shape)

for i in range(len(trainfiles)):
train_i = trainfiles[i].split()
imgpath = train_i[1]
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('data', 'train', imgpath))
img = cv2.resize(img, INPUT_SIZE) # resize
img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
x_train.append(img)
y_train.append(mapping[train_i[2]])

print('Shape of train images: ', x_train[0].shape)
```

Error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-5fa13deb65a6> in <module>()
 10     imgpath = test_i[1]
 11     img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('data', 'test', imgpath))
---> 12     img = cv2.resize(img, INPUT_SIZE) # resize
 13     img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
 14     x_test.append(img)
```

There are multiple questions about similar errors, but I do not see how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: if you `print(img .shape)` before `resize()` what size do you get? or `None`?

Comment: Where exactly to put it? I have something like AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape', but I am not sure I am doing it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: `print(os.path.join('data', 'test', imgpath))` and check if it is a file `os.path.isfile(os.path.join('data', 'test', imgpath))` ==> `True, False`, my guess a wrong path is given.